# JAVA: Trying to download file from URL with authentication

Tags: java, file, authentication, url, download

I have a problem with downloading a file from a URL with authentication.
I am pretty new to this topic and I need help from you guys! :(

I want to download a docx document from a url. If you would enter the url manually it would automatically download it for you. In my case, the file is on our intranet.

Here is what I got so far:
Main class

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Authenticator;
import java.net.CookieHandler;
import java.net.CookieManager;
import java.net.CookiePolicy;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.channels.Channels;
import java.nio.channels.ReadableByteChannel;

public class JavaDownloadFileFromURL {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CookieHandler.setDefault(new CookieManager(null, CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL));
        
        Authenticator.setDefault(new CustomAuthenticator());
        
        String url = "http://ourintranet.site.com/some/path/file.docx";
        
        try {
            
            downloadUsingStream(url, "/Users/Me/Documents/test.docx");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void downloadUsingStream(String urlStr, String file) throws IOException{
        URL url = new URL(urlStr);
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
        FileOutputStream fis = new FileOutputStream(file);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int count=0;
        while((count = bis.read(buffer,0,1024)) != -1)
        {
            fis.write(buffer, 0, count);
        }
        fis.close();
        bis.close();
    }
}
```

I figured out I needed an authenticator because previously I got the 401 error. So here is my authenticator:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.Authenticator;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.PasswordAuthentication;
import java.net.URL;

public class CustomAuthenticator extends Authenticator 
    {
  
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() 
        {
  
            String prompt = getRequestingPrompt();
  
            String hostname = getRequestingHost();
  
            InetAddress ipaddr = getRequestingSite();
  
            int port = getRequestingPort();
  
            String protocol = getRequestingProtocol();
  
            String scheme = getRequestingScheme();
  
            URL u = getRequestingURL();
  
            RequestorType rtype = getRequestorType();
  
            System.out.println("prompt:" + prompt);
            System.out.println("hostname:" + hostname);
            System.out.println("ipaddress:" + ipaddr);
            System.out.println("port:" + port);
            System.out.println("protocolo:" + protocol);
            System.out.println("scheme:" + scheme);
            System.out.println("URL:" + u);
            System.out.println("Requester Type:" + rtype);
  
            String username = "User123"; //hardcoded user
            String password = "pwd123"; //hardcoded pwd
  
            return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password.toCharArray());
  
        }
  
    }
```

My problem is, that I am getting the error: `java.net.ProtocolException: Server redirected too many  times (20)` and at this point I tried so many things and I don't know any further.

Can you guys help me out? :(

Thank you very much!

Comment: What did you mean by ("If you would enter the url manually it would automatically download it for you. ") ?  Do you mean if you try to download it by Browser?  It could be that you have a session cookie in your browser?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion! Yes, that is what I mean. If I would put it in the browser, it downloads it automatically.

Comment: You know what would help? IF you could open the Developer Toolbar in your Browser -- Go to Network --> Clear everything --> Paste your URL and click Enter --> Copy the Request from your Network Tab.

I dont know how the request looks like, so I cant help with it.  Your browser could be setting a session token automatically because you have a cookie?  Your browser could be sending authorization token because your username/password are stored?  Very hard to help!

:)

Comment: Ah! I found the error! It seems I was missing something in the authentication. Our server admin told me that we need an additional domain before the username. It now works fine. Thank you for your help! :)

Answer (score -2):

Ah! I found the error! It seems I was missing something in the authentication. Our server admin told me that we need an additional domain before the username. It now works fine.

Comment: This answer will be of no use to anybody else because it doesn't explain anything.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).